# how to get input from a pop up window

Tags: android, popupwindow, layout-inflater

```
//create inflater
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//create popupwindow
    PopupWindow pw=new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.dictionarylist)));

        Button Menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Menu);
        Menu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                pw.update(0, 0, 200, 250);
                pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
            }
        });
```

What i want is to show the popup window when i click the button in the parent activity. The popup window have buttons when onclick the button it do some functions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the view of the button and then assign the listener to it like this:

```
View pview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.dictionarylist));

Button Menu = (Button) pview.findViewById(R.id.Menu);

Menu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                pw.update(0, 0, 200, 250);
                pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
            }
```

Also initialize your inflator if you haven't already like this:

```
Inflator inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```